# clean message on topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a publisher to publish message to one topic at different time. Each time before I publish the new message, how can I clean the messages on the topic published at other time? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217590/clean-message-on-topic/) by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VitaliyProoks](https://answers.ros.org/users/882/vitaliyprooks/) on 2015-09-14**:
Why would you need that? After a subscriber receives a message, this message then vanishes. Probably what you actually need in your situation is to use services as they allow to publish messages only on requests.

**Comment by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on 2015-09-14**:
@VitaliyProoks Because I noticed that the robot didnot stop after publishing (0,0) to topic cmd_vel. I suspect that there  is velocity command on topic cmd_vel published at other time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Then it looks like it is issue in your robot's code, messaging in ROS works fine :) ROS provides tools for listening to/publishing from topics either from console or by means of `rqt_gui` try to debug by sending test messages and see what happens.

---

Originally posted by [VitaliyProoks](https://answers.ros.org/users/882/vitaliyprooks/) with karma: 75 on 2015-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2